# Append an object to a json file

Tags: json, perl

I'm trying to append

```
 {"create": {"_index":"socteam", "_type":"products"}}
```

To this json

```
{"general":{"date_time":"2016-04-1806:50:40","total_requests":12,"valid_requests":12,"failed_requests":0,"generation_time":0,"unique_visitors":12,"unique_files":11,"excluded_hits":0,"unique_referrers":0,"unique_not_found":0,"unique_static_files":0,"log_size":0,"bandwidth":1233,"log_path":"STDIN"},"visitors":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"20160418"}],"requests":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"2xxSuccess","items":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"200-OK:Therequestsentbytheclientwassuccessful"}]}]}
```

I have tried

```
{"create": {"_index":"socteam", "_type":"products"}},
{"general":{"date_time":"2016-04-1806:50:40","total_requests":12,"valid_requests":12,"failed_requests":0,"generation_time":0,"unique_visitors":12,"unique_files":11,"excluded_hits":0,"unique_referrers":0,"unique_not_found":0,"unique_static_files":0,"log_size":0,"bandwidth":1233,"log_path":"STDIN"},"visitors":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"20160418"}],"requests":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"2xxSuccess","items":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"200-OK:Therequestsentbytheclientwassuccessful"}]}]}
```

But I keep getting unexpected end of input, I'm trying to define an index for this data before its gets inserted to elastic search.

Comment: You need to decide upon a valid structure - do you want an array containing two objects, or to add a `create` key to the existing object, or what?

Comment: A JSON file can only contain one data structure. You currently have two. That is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting the comments you are because I think you didn't state your question correctly.

It appears that you're attempting to use the [elasticsearch bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html); is this correct?

If so, then what that API accepts is *multiple JSON documents*, separated by newlines. You **don't** combine the two JSON objects into another JSON file. Instead, you simply have the two objects as two separate JSON documents on different lines:

```
{"create": {"_index":"socteam", "_type":"products"}}
{"general":{"date_time":"2016-04-1806:50:40","total_requests":12,"valid_requests":12,"failed_requests":0,"generation_time":0,"unique_visitors":12,"unique_files":11,"excluded_hits":0,"unique_referrers":0,"unique_not_found":0,"unique_static_files":0,"log_size":0,"bandwidth":1233,"log_path":"STDIN"},"visitors":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"20160418"}],"requests":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"2xxSuccess","items":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"200-OK:Therequestsentbytheclientwassuccessful"}]}]}
```

No comma or anything.

Also, when you contact your elastic search machine, you are using the endpoint `/_bulk`, yes?

Answer (score 0):

As the commenters said, you either make a 2-element array, or merge two hashes togeather (resulting in the second clobbering any entries with identical keys);

```
use v5.12;
use JSON::Tiny qw(decode_json encode_json);

my $j1 = decode_json '{"general":{"date_time":"2016-04-1806:50:40","total_requests":12,"valid_requests":12,"failed_requests":0,"generation_time":0,"unique_visitors":12,"unique_files":11,"excluded_hits":0,"unique_referrers":0,"unique_not_found":0,"unique_static_files":0,"log_size":0,"bandwidth":1233,"log_path":"STDIN"},"visitors":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"20160418"}],"requests":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"2xxSuccess","items":[{"hits":12,"visitors":12,"percent":100.00,"bytes":1233,"data":"200-OK:Therequestsentbytheclientwassuccessful"}]}]}' ;

my $j2 = decode_json '{"create": {"_index":"socteam", "_type":"products"}}' ;

my @merged_array = ( %$j1 , %$j2 );
my %merged_hash  = ( %$j1 , %$j2 );

say encode_json \@merged_array ;
say "========================" ;
say encode_json \%merged_hash  ;
```

which produces;

```
["general",{"log_path":"STDIN","unique_static_files":0,"generation_time":0,"unique_referrers":0,"unique_not_found":0,"date_time":"2016-04-1806:50:40","failed_requests":0,"bandwidth":1233,"unique_files":11,"excluded_hits":0,"log_size":0,"total_requests":12,"valid_requests":12,"unique_visitors":12},"requests",[{"bytes":1233,"hits":12,"percent":100,"data":"2xxSuccess","items":[{"bytes":1233,"hits":12,"percent":100,"data":"200-OK:Therequestsentbytheclientwassuccessful","visitors":12}],"visitors":12}],"visitors",[{"bytes":1233,"hits":12,"percent":100,"data":"20160418","visitors":12}],"create",{"_index":"socteam","_type":"products"}]
========================
{"create":{"_index":"socteam","_type":"products"},"general":{"log_path":"STDIN","unique_static_files":0,"generation_time":0,"unique_referrers":0,"unique_not_found":0,"date_time":"2016-04-1806:50:40","failed_requests":0,"bandwidth":1233,"unique_files":11,"excluded_hits":0,"log_size":0,"total_requests":12,"valid_requests":12,"unique_visitors":12},"requests":[{"bytes":1233,"hits":12,"percent":100,"data":"2xxSuccess","items":[{"bytes":1233,"hits":12,"percent":100,"data":"200-OK:Therequestsentbytheclientwassuccessful","visitors":12}],"visitors":12}],"visitors":[{"bytes":1233,"hits":12,"percent":100,"data":"20160418","visitors":12}]}
```